# Guide for Tidying up code with promises and exports (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, promise

I managed to get this code working. But I would like to find out how to tidy it up. Please give me some guide.

In `index.js`, I have this code:

```
var API = require('./../controllers/rounds.js');

var getToken = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        API.getToken(function(err, token) {
             console.log('the token is' + token);
             resolve({data: 123});
         });
     });
     return promise;
};
```

In rounds.js I have:

```
  exports.getToken = function(callback) {

        exec('curl -s --data "" http://www.mysitehere.com/api | grep token | cut -d \\" -f4', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
             token = stdout;
             token = token.trim();
             if (error !== null)
                 callback(null, err);
             else
                 callback(null, token);
         });
     };
```

Ignoring the fact that I'm calling command line utilities that could probably be done in `javascript`. I want to know if I can move any of my lines from `index.js` to use `rounds.js`. Or if any of the lines are superfluous. Finally, I'd like to know what the resolve({data: 123}); does. And how i should use it with my data.

My end goal is to chain functions with promises like so. So, I would have:

```
getToken()
    .then(getCurrentRound);
```

and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As per the [ask] guidelines, please explain what this code does, and also make that the title of the question.

Comment: This side code simply calls the api and fetches a token for use in later calls such as getting the current round of a season. Its to do with sports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating a new promise like that should be very rare in your codebase. If you insist on using exec, make a wrapper around it and give it a promise interface. That way you can have the conversion between callback and promise limited to one place.

Remember to try/catch inside of new Promise, since exceptions are swallowed there.
Remember to reject when there is an error.

But of course, you could just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise